# why is square of $4945932$ coming out to be negative?

Tags: java, sqr

I declared an integer int i = 4945932;                                                                   and its square is coming out to be some negative random number.                             How is this possible? What am i doing wrong?                                                   Help please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `integer overflow` perhaps ?  If you are not familiar with the term or its causes, now would be a good time to Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Integer overflow.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) A Java int cannot be larger than 2,147,483,647; if you try to store a larger number, it overflows.

If you instead use a `long`, that can store much larger values, including the one you're trying to store. If you need even larger values, [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) can store arbitrary-precision integers; the only limit is your computer's memory.

Answer (score 2):

it happens because of the limit of the int. [integer OverFlow.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javas-silent-killer-buffer-overflow-careful/)

int can store 4 bytes, signed (two's complement). -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

if you write `int i= square(4945932)` it is 24462243348624 so it will exceed the limit of int so it behaves abnormal.

Comment: so what datatype should i choose to handle such integers?

Comment: you can use long or BigInteger.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
long l = 4945932L;
System.out.println(l * l);
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(4945932L);
System.out.println(bi.multiply(bi));
```

prints

```
24462243348624
24462243348624
```

Answer (score 1):

You are exceeding the size of an int. You will need to change to a long if you want to square 4945932.